# Number of categories

Tags: category-theory

How many categories have only two objects:
I'm thinking that the answer is three:

1. Without arrows between the objects
2. One arrow between the objects
3. Two arrows (back and forth) between the objects

Am I right or I can have an infinite number, maybe putting
arrows as many as I want?

Answer (score 8):

There are infinitely many categories with one object. They correspond to
monoids. Infinitely many? Even up to isomorphism, they form a proper class!

The same is true for two-object categories.

Comment: And also up to equivalence of categories, they still form a proper class.

Answer (score 6):

Remember that the source and target of an arrow do **not** determine the arrow! For example, consider the category with a single object $*$ and a morphism $z:*\rightarrow*$ for each $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ with composition given by $$m\circ n=m+n.$$ *(As an aside, note that this looks a lot like the group $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$; indeed, every group can be thought of as a one-object category in this way!)*

Comment: I see, nice example, thanks for sharing it.